# Get by id as well as by string angularjs webapi

Tags: angularjs, asp.net-web-api

I am completely new with angularjs using with webapi and I am probably going about it the wrong way but basically I want to search for a product by text(as I am executing the query in the database) as well as get a product by id for the purpose of updating the existing product.

The search by text I do as follow.

```
//productResource.js

        (function () {
        "use strict";

        angular.module("common.services").factory("productResource", ["$resource", "appSettings", productResource])

        function productResource($resource, appSettings) {

            return $resource(appSettings.serverPath + "/api/products/:search");
        }
    }());
```

And in my webApi controller

```
public IEnumerable<Product> Get(string search)
        {
            var repository = new ProductRepository();
            return repository.Restrieve(search); 
        }

        public Product Get(int id)
        {
            Product product;
            var repository = new ProductRepository();

            if (id > 0)
            {
                product = repository.GetProductById(id);
            }
            else
            {
                product = repository.CreateProduct();
            }

            return product;
        }
```

And then in my WebApiConfig:

```
 config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();

        config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
            name: "DefaultApi",
            routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{search}",
            defaults: new { search = RouteParameter.Optional }
        );
```

The way it is setup now I manage to do searches by text.

How can I configure **productResource.js** and **WebApiConfig** to making provision for a search by id as well?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would go with a slightly different routes here. In a RESTful API you have resources (products in your case). A resource is uniquely identified by `id`. So I would have the following route:

```
GET /products/:id
```

and if I wanted to search multiple products by text:

```
GET /products?search=xxxx
```

which would be just fine with the default routes:

```
config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
    name: "DefaultApi",
    routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
    defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
);
```

and now on the client side:

```
function productResource($resource, appSettings) {
    return $resource(appSettings.serverPath + 'api/products/:id');
}
```

and to query:

```
productResource.query({ id: '123'});
productResource.query({ search: 'some search text'});
```

Here's a [`nice overview`](http://masnun.com/2013/08/28/rest-access-in-angularjs-using-ngresource.html) with examples of `$resource`.

Also make sure you have read the [`following blog post`](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/ExperimentsInWackinessAllowingPercentsAnglebracketsAndOtherNaughtyThingsInTheASPNETIISRequestURL.aspx) before the next time you try to put search texts (or any arbitrary data coming from clients) in the path portion of your routes instead of where they belong -> the query string.